# How to bind properties with the collection Using OdataModel in SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

Hello Guys please i need your help.

Using a Mockserver i'm abel to get access zu OData like this way

```
var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("oServiceModel");
var sReservationPath = "/Book_Regal(Bibliothek='BE1',ReservationNr='4162')/Reserve_Book";
```

I bind my Form like this:

```
var formA = this.getView().byId("FormA");
formA.setModel(oModel, "Bibliothek");
formA.bindElement({path: "/Reserve_Book(Bibliothek='BE1',ReservationNr='4162')", model: "Bibliothek"});
```

My MockData(BookReserved.json) looks like this:

```
[
{
    "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "http://MyWebService/Reserve_Book(BibliothekName='BE1',ReservationNr='4162')",
                "uri": "http://MyWebService/Reserve_Book(BibliothekName='BE1',ReservationNr='4162')",
                "type": "infos.Reserve_BookType"
            },
            "iScomfirmed": true,
            "BibliothekName": "BE1",
            "ReservationNr": "4162",
            "BookType": "3021",
            "BookCategory": "2"               
        }
                ]
}
```

]

My SimpleForm looks like this

```
<Input  value="{Bibliothek/results[0]/>BibliothekName}" editable="false"> 
</Input>
```

What do i wrong ? Please can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your mock server works there are two errors.

The binding syntax is `{MODEL_NAME>PATH}` (if the name of the model is `undefined` or `''` you can omit the first part and just use `{PATH}`).

In your case `MODEL_NAME` is `Bibliothek`. `/results[0]/` is part of a path and not the model name so it can never appear before the `>` symbol.

Then when dealing with OData you will never use array indices (like `[0]`). OData entries have a proper key which has to be used (and you did already use it when calling `bindElement`).

Your form is then connected to your binding path. All elements below the form also have access to this information and can use it by setting a relative binding path so your code should look like

```xml
<Input value="{Bibliothek>BibliothekName}">
```

---

Just some examples which are all basically the same

#### Hardcoded absolute binding of element

*This only works if the entity has been already loaded in another request*

```xml
<form:SimpleForm>
   <Input value="{Bibliothek>/Reserve_Book(Bibliothek='BE1',ReservationNr='4162')/BibliothekName}" />
<form:SimpleForm />
```

#### Hardcoded absolute binding of parent, relativ binding of child

*This can trigger it's own request if the entity hasn't been already loaded*

```xml
<form:SimpleForm binding="{Bibliothek>/Reserve_Book(Bibliothek='BE1',ReservationNr='4162')}">
   <Input value="{Bibliothek>BibliothekName}" />
<form:SimpleForm />
```

#### Dynamic absolute binding of parent (in JS), relativ binding of child

*This behaves the same as the second example*

```js
this.byId("form").bindElement({path: "/Reserve_Book(Bibliothek='BE1',ReservationNr='4162')", model: "Bibliothek"});
```

```xml
<form:SimpleForm id="form">
   <Input value="{Bibliothek>BibliothekName}" />
<form:SimpleForm />
```

Comment: Thx Marc i change it: i first load the entity and bind it to my form. and was able now to read itz as you suggest    <Input value="{Bibliothek>BibliothekName}" />